How to programmatically sign .exe with Electron-Builder?
While attempting to make autoupdates work on windows with electron, I have encountered the error "New version not signed by application owner"
To fix this I assumed I need to sign every executable after the first one as well.
Here is what I currently have in package.json:
"win": {
  "publisherName": [
    "XXX"
  ],
  "icon": "build/icon.ico",
  "sign": "./sign.js"
},

and here is my sign.js file (same directory as package.json)
exports.default = async function(configuration) {
  // do not include passwords or other sensitive data in the file
  // rather create environment variables with sensitive data
  // const CERTIFICATE_NAME = process.env.WINDOWS_SIGN_CERTIFICATE_NAME;
  // const TOKEN_PASSWORD = process.env.WINDOWS_SIGN_TOKEN_PASSWORD;

  require("child_process").execSync(
    // your commande here ! For exemple and with JSign :
    `java -jar jsign.jar \
    --storetype GOOGLECLOUD \
    --storepass "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    --keystore "projects/XXX/locations/XXX/keyRings/XXX" \
    --alias "YYYY" \
    --certfile "ZZZZ" \
    --tsmode RFC3161 \
    --tsaurl http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 \
    './release/build/MyProgram Setup 6.4.1.exe'`
  );
};

If I build and then sign my exe right after everything works fine, but I need to be able to sign my exe while it goes through
electron-builder build --w --publish always

because I need autoupdates to work.
The error I get is:
The file ./release/build/MyProgram Setup 6.4.1.exe couldn't be found

which makes sense, but I have also tried
{stdio:"inherit"}

and that doesn't work either
Does anyone know how to fix this and do I even need to do all of this for autoupdates to work? (I saw another error in the logs stating that executables that aren't signed will not run...)
EDIT: Solved with this:
    exports.default = async function(configuration) {
  // do not include passwords or other sensitive data in the file
  // rather create environment variables with sensitive data
  // const CERTIFICATE_NAME = process.env.WINDOWS_SIGN_CERTIFICATE_NAME;
  // const TOKEN_PASSWORD = process.env.WINDOWS_SIGN_TOKEN_PASSWORD;
  console.log(configuration, "CONFIG for sign")
  require("child_process").execSync(
    // your commande here ! For exemple and with JSign :
    `java -jar jsign.jar \
    --storetype GOOGLECLOUD \
    --storepass "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    --keystore "projects/XXXX/locations/XXX/keyRings/XXX" \
    --alias "XXX" \
    --certfile "./path/to/certfile" \
    --tsmode RFC3161 \
    --tsaurl http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1 \
    "${configuration.path}"`,
    {
      stdio: "inherit"
    }
    
  );
};


stdio is not involved in resolving paths. To correctly resolve relative paths (those starting with ./), you'll need to specify the correct current working directory, known as CWD. You can do so by supplying the correct path as an option to execSync (see the docs), namely:
require ("child_process").execSync (/*your command*/, { cwd: "/path/to/your/project" });

Depending on the directory Electron Builder will be executed in, you may get away with specifying {cwd: __dirname} though you'd have to test this first.
Furthermore, you could get into trouble when the default shell for your system (on Unix, NodeJS uses /bin/sh) isn't set up correctly for your gcloud command expansion to work. If that's the case, you'll also need to supply the correct shell executable to be used by child_process using the option shell.

Thank you for your response, it turns out that I needed to use the absolute path which was passed in by configuration
